# I want to restrict access to Nextcloud using OpenVPN

Tags: firewalls, apache, openvpn

Is it a good idea to restrict access to my Nextcloud server by using OpenVPN, so every user (this is for small group of people), will get their own VPN account and after that they will be able to access to their account as well.

For the restriction part, I'm not sure how to manage that, probably on firewall side and on server side, using UFW or apache config.

```
<Location "/">
              Order deny,allow
              deny from all
              allow from 192.168.1.1
</Location>
```

What is your suggestion for this idea?

Comment: Just make the server listen only at the IP address of the VPN interface so that the server is only facing to the VPN but not to the public internet. Then the server is not even visible from the internet. See [Listen directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html) in Apache documentation.

Comment: This can be a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

Given that Nextcloud is designed to be an internet facing - e.g. "cloud" - solution, adding a VPN seems rather overkill unless you are planning to use it for very sensitive or high-value data.

Note that in using a VPN, you are committing yourself to getting the network design right **and** to ensuring that all the users have secure computers since you are allowing those devices into your secure network.

In my view, you would be better served spending a little time making sure that access to the Nextcloud server is properly configured. Also make sure that the server is constantly patched and that you are receiving security alerts from it so you know if someone/something is attacking.

Comment: If VPN is used *instead* of the usual hardening I would agree. But if it is used to restrict access *additionally* it is a valid part of security in depth.

Comment: Only if the VPN is correct and securely configured AND the client computers are also secure. This is potentially a much bigger attack surface than hardening a web service. This is important to note as too many people think that a VPN is some magic security solution and it absolutely isn't. You are allowing remote computers into an internal network, that *might* be much more secure but there are many ways to get it wrong including having a single compromised client machine.

Comment: I didn't get the feeling from the OP that they understood the complexities of security both the network and the client computers correctly - apologies to the OP if I got that wrong, the simplest solution is to secure the web interface and enforce strong passcodes - maybe add multi-factor auth if that is available.

Comment: If the OP does not get the security of the client system right it might be even worse to connect to the public internet using an insecure client than to connect only to the private cloud instance via VPN. Hardening the public available server does not make the clients more secure but requiring the clients to connect via the public internet just increases the attack surface of the clients.

Comment: Well it depends doesn't it. Depending on the architecture, a single server might be compromised or a whole network with multiple servers and other client machines (which may be exposed because they too are on the same VPN). We don't have enough information to make a definitive statement about what is best in this case. When in doubt, apply Occam's Razor. Simplicity often wins. Either *could* be the right answer.

Comment: Nextcloud is a php application with a large attack surface, while openvpn is a proven VPN protocol which works quite well with simple configurations. Forbidding all access from ips outside of the vpn eliminates the nextcloud attack surface completely. So while this is no comfortable solution for most users, it is a quite secure one if you trust the users which can login to the vpn.

Comment: I certainly don't disagree that a VPN _can_ be very secure. But adding complexity doesn't automatically make things more secure and a VPN is no magic bullet. The OP would be better served by far by paying experts to ensure the security of the cloud interface rather than paying for the complexity of a VPN and then having to pay again to make sure the end-to-end VPN routing is secure.